# Unity iOS Application Ipv6 support testing

Tags: ios, testing, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator, ipv6

I have submitted a Unity3D application to AppleMarket, but it has been rejected because of a bug: application works not as intended while connected to a IPv6 network.

I have a Mac virtual machine(thanks to VMware Workstation), and I need somehow to test my application on an iPad simulator on this virtual machine. The PC hosting virtual machine is connected to the Internet via router(cabel).

How do I enable IPv6 network to test my app?

Comment: There are many reasons why your app may be rejected due to IPv6 support. What is your Unity version? What are the network API's you used? Any network API such as WWW, Socket.....

Comment: @Programmer Unity 5.5.2, downloading data via WWW. But it is not the question. I could find the bugs on my own, if I only could test the application while connected to a IPv6 network.

Comment: *"But it is not the question"* It has something to do with a network API you are using or it is a bug from Apple side. Look and post [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-ios-and-ipv6-support.404938/page-3) for more support/

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in iOS. Than I change my reachblility class internet connection method and my app approved. I have not not more knowledge in Unity. But In iOS I am writing the code It will work for Ipv6. If You want to make Ipv6 network in your system than please check

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html

**Objective c**

```
 + (instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection
 {
  struct sockaddr_in6 zeroAddress;
  bzero(&zeroAddress, sizeof(zeroAddress));
  zeroAddress.sin6_len = sizeof(zeroAddress);
  zeroAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
  return [self reachabilityWithAddress: (const struct sockaddr *) &zeroAddress];
 }
```

**Swift 3**

```
func ipv6Reachability() -> SCNetworkReachability? 
{
var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in6()
zeroAddress.sin6_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout<sockaddr_in>.size)
zeroAddress.sin6_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET6)

return withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress, {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, $0)
    }
})
}
```